# JFreeChart: Adding key listener to ChartComposite in SWT

Tags: java, swt, jfreechart, keylistener

I am having a bit of trouble setting up a key listener to my ChartComposite object using SWT. Is this feature supported by ChartComposite?

My code looks as following:

```
chartComposite.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Key released: " + e.character);               
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Key pressed: " + e.character);
    }
});
```

I assume this is how a key listener should be added, nonetheless this code is never invoked.
I've seen some implementation for key listeners on the web but they all refer to `Swing` or `AWT`.
My question is how to do that in SWT?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure, that the `chartComposite` is focused (have focus), when are you trying to press the keys and react on them..?

Comment: @Sorceror Well, chartComposite is of type MyComposite which extends the ChartComposite. Inside MyComposite I override the zoom method and it works fine. I assume the object has the focus. Also I've noticed that there is no documentation on ChartComposite class on [JfreeChart's](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/index.html) website. Anyone knows where can I find it?

Comment: JFreeChart is known for lack of documentation, I've found only javadoc, check (javadocs for ChartComposite)[http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Chart/jfreechart-1.0.13/org/jfree/experimental/chart/swt/ChartComposite.java.java-doc.htm].. So your problem now is what? KeyListener is not invoked?

Comment: @Sorceror The link that you've provided was exactly what I needed. I was using javadoc as well, but no information about ChartComposite is present there. I posted my solution for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ChartComposite is not documented in the library's [Javadoc](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/index.html), so thanks to @Sorceror 's provided [link](http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Chart/jfreechart-1.0.13/org/jfree/experimental/chart/swt/ChartComposite.java.java-doc.htm) I found the correct way to do it.

```
public class MyChartComposite extends ChartComposite implements KeyListener
{

    public MyChartComposite(Composite comp, int style, JFreeChart chart, 
                                                      boolean useBuffer){
        super(comp, style, chart, useBuffer);
        addSWTListener(this);
    }   

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Key released: " + e.character);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Key pressed: " + e.character);
    }
}
```

The reason I chose to extend the ChartComposite is simply to allow adding more functionality to it in a much cleaner way.
Now you can use the above declared class to instantiate the object that will capture key events:

```
chartComposite = new MyChartComposite(parent, SWT.NONE, chart, true);
```